# JavaFX ToggleButton set color and restore default color

Tags: java, css, javafx, togglebutton

What is normal background color and border color on toggle button? example:

```
i.toggle11.setOnAction(e->{
        if(i.toggle11.isSelected()){
            i.toggle11.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
             i.toggle12.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");
             i.toggle13.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");
        }
        else {
             i.toggle11.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");
        }
    });
```

I want to after this action to put other toggles 'normal color'(same when togglebutton was created)

Answer (score 1):

**To answer how to add/remove styles**

The simplest approach if you color your `ToggleButton`s by adding a CSS styleclass, then when it is not needed anymore you remove them, therefore it will have the same style as before your formatting.

**Example**

*Code to add*

```
i.toggle11.setOnAction(e->{
        if(i.toggle11.isSelected()){
            i.toggle11.getStyleClass().add("red-button");
            i.toggle12.getStyleClass().add("white-button");
            i.toggle13.getStyleClass().add("white-button");
        }
        else{
             i.toggle13.getStyleClass().add("white-button");
        }
    });
```

*Then Code to remove*

```
i.toggle11.getStyleClass().removeAll("red-button", "white-button");
```

*CSS*

```
.red-button {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.white-button {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Just make sure that you have added the stylesheet which contains the CSS styles like:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

**But**

I don't know what you want to achieve, but if you want to just simply color your `ToggleButton` when it is selected, you can also overwrite `.toggle-button:selected` in your stylesheet and no other styling needed:

```
.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

It is always the simplest way to overwrite existing CSS classes and pseudoclasses. This is a good starting point to learn working with `ToggleButton`s and to style them: [Using JavaFX UI Controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/toggle-button.htm).

You can for example check the available style classes for `.toggle-button` [here](https://gist.github.com/bionicrm/c90c03c645d18722ddb0) and also you can check the [CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#togglebutton).

Comment: What is `.toggle-button:selected`? to what that dot is connected to?

Comment: Dot is the class selector in CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp.